# Trying to embed php within my twig files whilst using userfrosting

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig, slim, userfrosting

I need to include some form of API call within my userfrosting site, however I am finding it difficult to find a way to do this.
I have seen that one of the ways to add PHP to twig files is by creating an extension, but this does not seem to be what I'm looking for exactly.

I need to be able to pull data using a third party API which I have previously been using PHP to make calls with, however if any of you think I should use a different method to do this I am open to suggestions

TIA

Comment: An extension seems like the solution.  Perhaps explain the problem in a bit more detail.

Comment: What sort of API is this?  Generally speaking, you should be able to make your API call in the **controller**, and then pass any content retrieved from that API into your template via the call to `render`.

Answer (score 2):

For Userfrosting >4.1, in your sprinkle/composer.json file, add a requirement to include Guzzle:
`"require": {"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0"}`

(remember to run `composer update` to install the new dependency.

[Guzzle Docs](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/)

Then in your [controller](https://learn.userfrosting.com/routes-and-controllers) include guzzle:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException;
```

then you can initiate guzzle with:

```
$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => $config['api']['host'].'/',
    'timeout' => 5 // your timeout param
]);
```

(I set my api host in the sprinkle config, using an environment variable, so its not hardcoded.)

you can then make a POST request as follows, returning the response into a variable.

```
$api_response = $client->post('your_api_route', [
    'json' => [
        'api_param_1' => 'Hello',
        'api_param_2' => 'World!'
    ]
]);
```

Also reccomended the wrap the last bit in a `try` and catch an guzzle/http exceptions.

If your response is a JSON document, you can retrieve the contents into an array with:

```
$data = json_decode($api_response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I talk to an API in my userfrosting setup within the controller called by my route, then pass that data to my template. Check out the [first tutorial](http://www.userfrosting.com/tutorials/lesson-1-new-page/) on how to create a new template and pass data to it. Do whatever with PHP that you need to within the route (via a controller).

Comment: Thanks! Worked a charm!

Comment: Cool. Give me the "correct answer" if you could. Catch us in the chat room for more informal help